# Is there anyway to delete object from queryset that already chosen in django?

Tags: python, django, database

Example:

```
query = Test.objects.all()
```

I want to delete the specific one.
But before deletion I want to do some function like so.

```
for q in query:
   if q.name == something:
      newq = q.relate_set.all()
      query.remove(q) # this remove not work
```

Comment: just call q.delete(), that should work.

Comment: @SumeetKumar really not what they asked for.

Comment: Do you want to actually delete the row from the database?  Or just filter it out of the queryset?

Comment: @hop i thought he want to delete that instance, if he want to exclude the he can do `query.exclude(q)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just figure it out.

Just change it to list type and then delete it.

And I can use those elements in the list like queryset.And I don't know why.

Can anyone explain?

Thanks anyway.